# Delay in sql server query result with leading and trailing character removed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query in **SQL Server 2012** that takes 8 seconds to retrieve 1158 rows. In the query I have to join on two fields, I have to trim leading and trailing 0s while joining.

below Query : It takes 8 seconds to get 1158 rows

```
Select value1, value2
from TableA LEFT JOIN TableB
ON 
SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(TableA.[policy#]),PATINDEX('%[^' + '0' + ' ]%',REVERSE(TableA.[policy#])),100)),PATINDEX('%[^' + '0' + ' ]%',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(TableA.[policy#]),PATINDEX('%[^' + '0' + ' ]%',REVERSE(TableA.[policy#])),100))),100)
  = SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(TableB.[policy#]),PATINDEX('%[^' + '0' + ' ]%',REVERSE(TableB.[policy#])),100)),PATINDEX('%[^' + '0' + ' ]%',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(TableB.[policy#]),PATINDEX('%[^' + '0' + ' ]%',REVERSE(TableB.[policy#])),100))),100)  
  WHERE {some conditions}
```

Instead of writing the ugly code for removing leading and trailing 0s I have created two functions to do the same

```
  ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[L_TRIM](@String VARCHAR(MAX), @Char varchar(5))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
   RETURN SUBSTRING(@String,PATINDEX('%[^' + @Char + ' ]%',@String),100)
END

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[R_TRIM](@String VARCHAR(MAX), @Char varchar(5))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
  RETURN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@String),PATINDEX('%[^' + @Char + ' ]%',REVERSE(@String)),100))
END
```

Below Query : It takes 1 minute 40 seconds to get 1158 rows

```
Select value1, value2
from TableA LEFT JOIN TableB
ON 
 dbo.L_trim(dbo.R_trim( TableA.[policy#], '0'),'0') = dbo.L_trim(dbo.R_trim(TableB.[policy#], '0'),'0') 
 WHERE {some conditions}
```

Can someone guide me how can I retrieve the rows in lesser time without writing ugly code ?

Comment: How many rows do the tables contain? Are the tables indexed? Can you show us the where statement?

Comment: There are indexes and there are 2000 and 3500 rows in these two tables.

Comment: Ok. Is the index an integer? Have you ever reorganized / rebuilt it? Is one of those tables on a linked server?

Comment: You have discovered the truth behind the common comment "scalar functions can be performance killers". Absent a change to the schema or the way you store information in this column, the logical choice is to revert back to the original query and accept the "ugly" as a requirement to overcome the design issues.